# xsl 1.0 copy-of loses formatting in xsl-fo output

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

My xml is as follows:

```
<valid_path>
    <document var_name="some_value">
        <processControls>
            <p>Lots of good text here ...</p>
            <ul class="unIndentedList">
                <li> Graphical display of system</li>
                <li> Other bulleted items ...</li>
            </ul>
            <p>etc. etc. etc.</p>
        </processControls>
    </document>
</valid_path>
```

My input is determined by this:

```
<xsl:variable name="processControlsValue" select="/valid_path/document[@var_name='some_value']/processControls" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
```

I am calling a recursive template to replace a given string found in some input. The call is as follows.

```
<xsl:call-template name="bulRep">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$processControlsValue"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'Graphical'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'foofoobars'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Here is the template.

```
<xsl:template name="bulRep">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="by"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="bulRep">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="$text" />-->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The template works as far as replacing the text if it is found. (e.g. 'Graphical' does get replaced with 'foofoobars') The issue I am having is losing the formatting with value-of OR copy-of. I realize value-of is going to return text, not text and formatting, and I found many posts instructing  others to use copy-of to retain the formatting. This, however, is not working. The output is just a continuous line of text.

Now if I use the apply-templates line (currently commented out) instead of the value-of line and I make sure I'm hitting the 'otherwise' part of the template, I get the desired output. I'll get the paragraphs, bulleted lists, etc. But using value-of or copy-of only gets the text and using apply-templates will break if there is a string match.

My end result is a PDF using xsl-fo.

What I am seeing now:

Lots of good text here ... foofoobars display of system Other bulleted items ... etc. etc. etc.

What I want to see:

Lots of good text here ...

• foofoobars display of system

• Other bulleted items ...

etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting the variable **$processControlsValue**. The find and replace template assumes it is being passed just text, but if you pass it a variable had contains a list of nodes, then it won't work as expected. Could you edit you question to show a sample of your input, and the output you expect, then we can help adapt your approach. I don't think it will need any major change though. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC - Thanks for the follow up. I've added my input. The input is displayed correctly in the output using apply-templates. I would just stop there. However, there are layout issues I need to correct, so that is why I need to use the recursive replacement template.

Comment: We need to see the XML structure of the input you have.

Comment: I've updated my post with the xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if the find-and-replace template you are using is only designed to handled text being passed in as a parameter. If you are passing in a list of nodes, then when you come to do string functions like "contains", it will just use the text of the first node. Or if you are passing in a single element, which has multiple descendents, the string value is taken to be the concatenation of all descendant text nodes.

I think what you may need to do, is make use of the identity transform here, which is probably what you are doing already as you mention about **xsl:apply-templates**, but have a separate template to match text nodes, in which you can then call the find-and-replace template

```
<xsl:template ....>
  <xsl:variable name="processControlsValue" 
                select="/valid_path/document[@var_name='some_value']/processControls" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$processControlsValue" mode="replace">
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'Graphical'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'foofoobars'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::text())]" mode="replace">
  <xsl:param name="replace"/>
  <xsl:param name="by"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="replace">
  <xsl:param name="replace"/>
  <xsl:param name="by"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="bulRep">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Note, I have used `mode="replace"` to prevent potential clashing with out templates you might have. It might be possible to remove the mode if you there is no such clash.

So, the idea is within these two templates, it copies any existing elements and attributes, but when it finds a text node, it then does the find-and-replace on the text only.

As an aside, if you are using XSLT 2.0, you can just use the **replace** function instead of your named template

```
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="replace">
   <xsl:param name="replace"/>
   <xsl:param name="by"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $replace, $by)" />
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: As a full working example, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="processControlsValue" select="/valid_path/document[@var_name='some_value']/processControls"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$processControlsValue" mode="replace">
         <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'Graphical'"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'foofoobars'"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::text())]" mode="replace">
      <xsl:param name="replace"/>
      <xsl:param name="by"/>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()" mode="replace">
      <xsl:param name="replace"/>
      <xsl:param name="by"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="bulRep">
         <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
         <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="bulRep">
      <xsl:param name="text"/>
      <xsl:param name="replace"/>
      <xsl:param name="by"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="bulRep">
               <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/><!--<xsl:apply-templates select="$text" />-->
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to you sample XML, the following is output. As can be seen, the word 'Graphical' has been replaced by 'foofoobars' in the text.

```
<processControls>
<p>Lots of good text here ...</p>
<ul class="unIndentedList">
<li> foofoobars display of system</li>
<li> Other bulleted items ...</li>
</ul>
<p>etc. etc. etc.</p>
</processControls>
```

Comment: I'm actually getting no output now. Perhaps I misunderstood what my suggested next step might be. The processing lands correctly in the template match="@*|node()[not(self::text())]" template. However I don't see any text (formatted or plain) in the output.

Comment: I've added a full working copy of some XSLT to demonstrate it. It's possible you are doing other things in your XSLT which are clashing, but hopefully it should demonstrate the principal.

Comment: Perhaps some confusion came about due to my posting/editing in chunks. The issue isn't getting the text replacement working, but rather keeping the formatting. I've updated the OP with how it looks after running through the replace template and how I expect it to look. Running through the working copy (thanks for that) by itself also loses the paragraphs and bulleted list.

Comment: I ran my final XSLT sample at http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/eBz6Um and it appears to keep the "p" and "li" elements as expected. Something that is confusing me is that the question talks about outputing xsl-fo, but the XML sample actually contains HTML. Is some other process running after the text is replaced? Perhaps the issue lies there?

Comment: Just working with the standalone, I have the xsl attached to the xml and I'm viewing the xml in a browser (Firefox 23). The output is just one line of text for me.

Comment: Aha! The problem may be you are not outputting HTML here, but xml.  (The element "processControls" is not HTML after all). However, try changing the output method to "html" not "xml" in the xsl:output element, and see if that makes a difference.